# Passing IEnumerable<int> as parameter to WCF service

Tags: c#, .net, xml, web-services, wcf

I got xml looking like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<items>
    <item>1</item>
    <item>2</item>
    <item>3</item>
</items>
```

And a wcf service contract:

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "", Name = "MyService", SessionMode = SessionMode.NotAllowed)]
public interface IMyService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
    void DoWork(IEnumerable<int> items);
}
```

Service binding is basic http.
But when i try to post that xml to wcf method i'm getting error:
`Unable to deserialize XML message with root name "items" and root namespace ""`

How should wcf method look like to properly work with that xml?

Comment: Try to get the WSDL of your service. Does the contract schema match with your XML?

Comment: @MauriceStam for same reason as in question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21127021/add-behaviorattribute-to-a-workflowservicehost i'm unable to see wsdl. I just need to make service understand xml format i provided

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your service contract does not seem to be setup correctly.

I think you need to implement a "wrapper" class, which defines a type structure that matches your XML.

For example:

```
[XmlRoot("items")]
public class MyItems
{
    [XmlElement("item")]
    public List<int> Items { get; set; }
}
```

I just put together a quick test app and successfully verified the interface using your sample XML (via a soapUI REST client).

Regards,

Comment: Thanks a lot! Got it working with method marked by `XmlSerializerFormat` attribute

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to specify a root namespace for default xml deserialization. If this is not an option for you, you might need to change your service interface to accept a stream instead.

Here's more information on the subject: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35982/REST-WCF-and-Streams-Getting-Rid-of-those-Names-Sp

<strike>To actually answer your question</strike>, you could try the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<items xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/" 
    xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <item>1</item>
    <item>2</item>
    <item>3</item>
</items>
```

Edit: That was not your question. So to *actually* answer your question:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(BodyStyle =
    WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,)] 
    void DoWork(Stream data);
```

Another alternative could be a custom datacontract (signature: `void DoWork(MyCustomDataContract data);`) and custom deserialization, example here:
[How to use Custom Serialization or Deserialization in WCF to force a new instance on every property of a datacontact ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8084868/how-to-use-custom-serialization-or-deserialization-in-wcf-to-force-a-new-instanc)

Comment: can't do anything with xml, just service

Comment: hmm at least I managed to offer a more complicated alternative :P Seymor's answer is obviously a lot cleaner